# How to create a javascript date from 12 hour format

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, frontend

How can I create a Date object from a date with this format:

> 03/23/2016 02:00:00 PM

Comment: This question has been asked [*many, many times*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5Dparse+date+string). Manually parse strings, either write a function or use a library. **DO NOT** use the Date constructor or Date.parse (they are equivalent for parsing strings). If you wan a simple parser and formatter, consider [*date-format.js*](https://github.com/barbir/js-date-format/blob/master/js/date-format.js).

Comment: Thanks @RobG! Sorry I didn't know what to search honestly.. tried too specific I guess and didn't find what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object can parse strings: `new Date('03/23/2016 02:00:00 PM')`

For example:

```
var date = new Date('03/23/2016 02:00:00 PM') // => "Wed Mar 23 2016 14:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
date.getFullYear() // => 2016
```

However, I would recommend using a library that someone else has already spent time considering the edge cases, like time zones, etc. (a good one I've used is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)).

Keep in mind (from the moment.js docs):

> Warning: Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.
>
> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: The moment.js documentation is not an authority on ECMAScript, please use ECMA-262 for that. In this case, the moment.js documentation is wrong, support for a limited selection of ISO 8601 formats was introduced in ES5, however support is still inconsistent and not to be relied upon. Also, even current browsers do not correctly parse ISO formats, so **always** specify the format or use a bespoke parser.

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date("3/23/2016 02:00:00 PM");
console.log(date);
```

You can then access all the methods of the Date object.

Comment: No, do not do that. Parsing of strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, it is equivalent) is unreliable. Just don't do it.

Comment: @RobG - Thank you, you make an excellent point.  Where the code will be used is an important consideration.  If it is a small project for learning, the most expeditous solution may well be the best.  If it is targeted for any professional solution, it should be implemented with strict adherence to standards and best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
var date = new Date('03/23/2016 02:00:00 PM')

Comment: MDN is not an authority on anything, it's a (very helpful) public wiki that anyone can contribute to. There is no requirement in the language specification for that format string to be parsed at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like date.js:
First use script, then write date:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js"></script> 
....
document.write(new Date().toString("dd:MM:yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
```

Comment: Parsing **must** include the format too, otherwise the results are unreliable.